# Determining the "Region" Touched in a UIImageView

Tags: ios, uiimageview, gesture

I'm trying to determine the *region* or *area* of an image that a user touches.

For example, I would like to have a `CGRect` to define the location of each letter so I can determine when the user touches the "O" in one of the following images…

[image: Example Image]

My first idea was to use `locationInView` to give me the absolute coordinates and adjust them to the relative size of the `ImageView`.  However, since I'm using `AspectFit` for the content mode, the relative location of a given region changes with every screen size and orientation because of the image *padding* on the top/bottom and sides.

In a perfect solution, I would also like to embed this image in a `ScrollView` so it can be zoomed.  But, I can forgo that if necessary.

I don't work with gestures and images very often, so I may be missing something obvious.  Any help or ideas you provide will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: But why you're using whole image instead of separated images of all these letters? Or why not to use UIButtons and just set a letters accordingly?

Comment: The reason is the "ABC…" picture was for simplicity of explanation.  Perhaps I made it too simple.  The actual imageView is a real image.  For example, I could have used a picture of the Northern Hemisphere and wanted to know when they touched the US, China, or Switzerland.

Answer (score 0):

There is the easy way and the hard way. The easy way it to break this image down into smaller images, one for each letter. The problem with this approach is making them line up as the single image did. If you take this approach you can use CGRectContainsPoint to see which image you tapped. Or you can make each of them buttons or give each image a gesture recognizer to identify what was pressed. If your design is requires you to use a single image then you'll have to make a hitmap describing each location. Each letter will require its own CGMutablePathRef with a CGPathMoveToPoint and a few CGPathAddLineToPoint to describe its shape and location. The method CGPathContainsPoint will tell you which one you hit.

Comment: Andrew, thank you for your prompt response.  First, if you wouldn't mind reading my answer to "arturdev."  Second, the problem I'm running into is points and paths change for each device and orientation.  I'm trying to develop a device/orientation independent solution.